# How to apply a custom function to a column that generates columns/dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function (based on a condition being true) to return the multiplication of an integer and a selected vector which would then be appended onto the right-hand side of the dataframe. However, it keeps on returning 'empty dataframe'. I'm new to Python and still so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#example data
data = {'Condition':  ['C','D','A','C'], 
'Values':[10,20,30,40], 
'Ftype':[3,3,3,3] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#example profiles which change depending on the letter of the alphabet and consist of variations over time

profile = {'profile_ID':  ['A','B','C','D','E','F'], 
'Period1':[0.1,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.2,0.1],
'Period2':[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
'Period3':[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
'Period4':[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]}

profile = pd.DataFrame(profile)


#custom function
def Custom_function (Ftype):
    if  Ftype > 2:
        return_array = df['Values'] * profile    
                
    return return_array



#to create a new dataframe by applying the custom function
dfx=df['Ftype'].apply(Custom_function)

#this could then be joined into the main df 

###########
#I was hoping for some like (showing 1st row only to save me typing it all)

Condition   Values     Ftype     Period1     Period2     Period3    Period4
C            10          3          1           0           1          2

############
#this is the return it comes back with
0        0   1   2   3  Period1  Period2  Period3  ...
1        0   1   2   3  Period1  Period2  Period3  ...
2        0   1   2   3  Period1  Period2  Period3  ...
3        0   1   2   3  Period1  Period2  Period3  ...
Name: Ftype, dtype: object
```

I'm stuck...Other ways I have thought about trying is 'groupby' and then picking out a 'C' from the df and a 'C' from the profiles and applying it, but that is probably slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the dataframes

```
df1 = df.merge(profile, how='left', left_on='Condition', right_on='profile_ID')


print(df1)
#   Condition  Values  Ftype profile_ID  Period1  Period2  Period3  Period4
# 0         C      10      3          C      0.1      0.0      0.1      0.2
# 1         D      20      3          D      0.0      0.0      0.1      0.2
# 2         A      30      3          A      0.1      0.0      0.1      0.2
# 3         C      40      3          C      0.1      0.0      0.1      0.2
```

Mask the values where Ftype is <= 2

```
v = df1['Values'].mask(df1['Ftype'] <= 2)

print(v)
# 0    10
# 1    20
# 2    30
# 3    40
# Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

Filter the period like columns and multiply by values along index axis

```
p = df1.filter(like='Period').mul(v, axis=0)

print(p)
#    Period1  Period2  Period3  Period4
# 0      1.0      0.0      1.0      2.0
# 1      0.0      0.0      2.0      4.0
# 2      3.0      0.0      3.0      6.0
# 3      4.0      0.0      4.0      8.0
```

Update the dataframe with new period values

```
df1.update(p)

print(df1)
#   Condition  Values  Ftype profile_ID  Period1  Period2  Period3  Period4
# 0         C      10      3          C      1.0      0.0      1.0      2.0
# 1         D      20      3          D      0.0      0.0      2.0      4.0
# 2         A      30      3          A      3.0      0.0      3.0      6.0
# 3         C      40      3          C      4.0      0.0      4.0      8.0
```

Comment: I can't upvote yet, but thank you!

Comment: @Pgmr_Beginner Feel free to accept the answer if you think it answer your question